# @Grab with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, httpbuilder

I'm trying the following @Grab from Eclipse

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
```

When i run it though, Eclipse just stops responding.

This one works.

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:0.8.0')
```

Is there anything I should before I execute the @Grab? 
Also, I'd like to be able to @Grab wslite version 1.1.0. How can I do that? If I just change the version to 1.1.0, it stops responding again.

I'm very new to Groovy so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you behind a proxy?  is ws-lite 0.8.0 already in your `~/.m2/repository`?

Comment: No proxy. No ws-lite 0.8.0 in my ~/.m2/repository either. I can grab HTTP Builder now. What's left is grab on ws-lite 1.1.0.

Comment: great.  but i guess, there hardly anything SO can do here, now that it works?

Comment: you can start by getting more information about what's going on. Add the following to your groovy script run configuration VM arguments:  -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true

Comment: I added the argument and tried grabbing version 1.1.0 again. I don't get anything, it just loads forever.